# AWS SDK What context do applications run in for ACL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

We're using the AWS SDK (.net) and have successfully uploaded files through our program using PutObjectRequest. I know how to set the ACL permissions on the file once it's created, But when trying to Get the file using GetObjectRequest our application is getting "Access Denied". I realize that I don't know what the userID is for the application that's running. How can I make sure my application has the permissions needed to read the file, without using "public" rights? (setting the ACL on the file to public works for the application).

Is there a way to make the application retrieve a file AS a certain user or group?

Comment: You say below you are using an S3 compatible service. Does any of this actually run on AWS itself?  Where is the application running? Can you clarify what resource you are setting ACL permission for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any AWS API call request, need an **access key and secret key** pair which can be set from:

1. Hard coded in the app,
2. AWS configuration file (by default it is in `~/.aws/credentials` or `C:\Users\*USERNAME*\.aws\credentials`), or
3. Instance role for EC2 instances.

For the #1 and #2, you can check your IAM user permission in https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#users.

For #3, you can check your IAM role in https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home?region=us-east-1#roles.

Make sure the user/role have enough permission to read your S3 object. You can attach this policy into the user/role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmt1455021573875",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetObject",
        "s3:GetObjectAcl"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::your-bucket-name/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Adjust the above policy. Your app should have read object access now.

Btw, you can set ACL while *creating* a resource. You can find the documentation on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-using-dot-net-sdk.html.

```
static string bucketName = "*** Provide existing bucket name ***";
static string newBucketName = "*** Provide a name for a new bucket ***";
static string newKeyName = "*** Provide a name for a new key ***";

IAmazonS3 client;
client = new AmazonS3Client(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

// Retrieve ACL from one of the owner's buckets
S3AccessControlList acl = client.GetACL(new GetACLRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
}).AccessControlList;

// Describe grant for full control for owner.
S3Grant grant1 = new S3Grant
{
    Grantee = new S3Grantee { CanonicalUser = acl.Owner.Id },
    Permission = S3Permission.FULL_CONTROL
};

// Describe grant for write permission for the LogDelivery group.
S3Grant grant2 = new S3Grant
{
    Grantee = new S3Grantee { URI = "http://acs.amazonaws.com/groups/s3/LogDelivery" },
    Permission = S3Permission.WRITE
};

PutBucketRequest request = new PutBucketRequest()
{
    BucketName = newBucketName,
    BucketRegion = S3Region.US,
    Grants = new List<S3Grant> { grant1, grant2 }
};
PutBucketResponse response = client.PutBucket(request);

PutObjectRequest objectRequest = new PutObjectRequest()
{  
    ContentBody = "Object data for simple put.",
    BucketName = newBucketName,
    Key = newKeyName,
    Grants = new List<S3Grant> { grant1 }
};
PutObjectResponse objectResponse = client.PutObject(objectRequest);
```

Comment: So we're using aws SDK to connect to an "S3 compatible" storage but not Amazon s3 itself. We do have a secret key and access key, and I have set ACL when uploaidng the file, but when downloading the file, we get access denied. I don't know if I'm setting ACL permissions for the correct group because I don't know what group the access/secret keys is set to. That's kind of where my question lies, how can I see or force the user behind a specific secret/access key so I know what the API is using to read the file?

Comment: In AWS you can check the owner of access key by using [IAM](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/list-access-keys.html). But, as you said, you are using another vendor. I think you need to specify the vendor that you use.